# Safari Browser How to detect when Block cookies from Privacy is NOT set to Never?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, bookmarklet

I developed a bookmarklet using Javascript and my bookmarklet does not work on Safari browser on Windows or Mac, when Block cookies is NOT set on Never.

go to Settings, Preferences, Privacy, Block cookies

How do i detect the value of this option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my bookmarklet does not work on Safari browser.

So at some point in the code, you want something to happen that does not happen. (Most likely, that a cookie can't be set and then read.)

> how do i detect the value of this option

You detect that what you wanted to happen, didn't happen.

I'm pretty sure that there is no way to directly read this browser setting. You can only assume the setting based on testing if you can set a cookies and then read it.